# Incorrect xsl:copy output

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to copy all info from my xml file (actually i need to add new info into my xml file).

I use standart template :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and I write test xml file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE products SYSTEM "products.dtd" >
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../xsl/copy.xsl"?>
    <products>
        <category name="Audio And Video">
            <subcategory name="Audio">
                <good>
                    <producer>Dell</producer>
                    <model>QQ678</model>
                    <color>White</color>
                    <date_of_issue>12-12-2012</date_of_issue>
                    <not_in_stock>true</not_in_stock>
                </good>
            </subcategory>
            <subcategory name="Video">
                <good>
                    <producer>Samsung</producer>
                    <model>VH500</model>
                    <color>Black</color>
                    <date_of_issue>12-12-2006</date_of_issue>
                    <price>200</price>
                </good>
                <good>
                    <producer>Toshiba</producer>
                    <model>GP436</model>
                    <color>White</color>
                    <date_of_issue>12-12-2004</date_of_issue>
                    <not_in_stock>true</not_in_stock>
                </good>
            </subcategory>
        </category>
        <category name="Computers">
            <subcategory name="Pocket">
                <good>
                    <producer>HP</producer>
                    <model>rx371</model>
                    <color>Black</color>
                    <date_of_issue>31-01-2006</date_of_issue>
                    <not_in_stock>true</not_in_stock>
                </good>
            </subcategory>
        </category>
</products>
```

And when i open this xml file in browser I think I will see the same xml file but it displays me: [image]

so where I made mistake. Please help me please to solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your style sheet does nothing except copy the input to the output. As far as can be told from the browser output, it is doing that correctly. There is no problem in evidence here. Try outputting some HTML instead of just copying.

Comment: but I want to copy all my xml file and then add some info into it

Comment: on many sites I see info that this template copy all nodes into result file

Comment: why the output look like this. without tags

Comment: Your output is absolutely corret. It's the browser that is not showing tags! Just do once "show source" and you'll see the source. Have you ever saw any tags when surfing in Internet showing HTML (sort of XML)? The browser is interpreting tags and not showing them!